# database.yml не читает erb код

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, yml, erb

Конфигурацию храню в переменном окружении машины, в database.yml прописываю:

```
development:
   adapter: mysql
   user:  <%= ENV['CAB_DB_USER'] || 'root' %>
   password:  <%= ENV['CAB_DB_PASSWORD'] || '******' %>
   host:  <%= ENV['CAB_DB_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
   database: <%= ENV['CAB_DB_NAME'] || 'cabinet' %>
```

Во всех остальных проектах прекрасно работает, конкретно в этом упирается:

```
Unknown MySQL server host '<% ENV['CAB_DB_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>' (25) (DataObjects::SQLError)
```

Просто не читает erb и все. Что с ним не так? Как на это повлиять?

Comment: Версии Ruby, Rails?

Comment: @D-side Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3, Rails 3.2.13

Comment: Ох блин. А намеренно такие древние?

Comment: @D-side проекты старые и здоровые, я пока один облагораживаю их, а переводить на новые версии нет ресурсов.

Comment: То есть, намеренно, ок. "Во всех остальных проектах" с такими же версиями?

Comment: @D-side именно, а тут просто не интерепретирует erb код из yml

Comment: Интересно. А попробуйте из `irb`/`pry` провернуть [то же, что делают рельсы](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L113).

Comment: @D-side Самое интересное, что за минуту до вашего ответа я отдебажил инициалайзер, и нашел, что приложение использует кастомную ОРМ, и конфиг читается не рельсами, а самописной библиотекой, и при чтении конфига просто читается YAML, без интерпретации IRB и как только я переписал ту строку, на подобную той что вы отлинковали, все заработало, и сразу после этого прочитал ваш комментарий. Вчера видимо уж слишком устал, и не додумался дебажить инит файлы.

Comment: Хе-хе. Да, свободой в Ruby легко злоупотребить :) Есть два варианта: закрыть вопрос по "не воспроизводится" (поскольку связан с кодом, который вы не можете раскрывать третьим лицам), или описать процедуру отладки на минимальном воспроизводимом примере (если это не просто "нашёл, чем открывается"; т. к. вопрос, выходит, даже не о Rails) в ответе, потенциально получив пару плюсиков.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что приложении используется кастомная ОРМ, и самописное чтение конфига не учитывает нахождение `erb` кода в конфигурационном файле, это выглядит как:

```
cfg = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config','database.yml'))
```

Нужно просто добавить чтение `erb`:

```
cfg = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read("#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")).result)
```